# Chrome keyboard shortcut for paste and search?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

Chrome keyboard shortcut for paste and search?

When we right click the address bar, there is an option for us to do "paste and search". I'm wondering is there an alternative shortcut for **Ctrl-V** + **Enter** (it's really slow, since Enter is on the right side of my keyboard)?

Comment: If you are copying material from a website open in the browser itself, you can also simply highlight the text, right-click and select 'Search Google for 'highlighted text.'

Comment: Following on from @Mahendru, this also works for URLs except it will say "Go to <selected URL>."

Comment: if you think this should really be a feature and it is not go ahead and file a bug with Chromium Issue list

Comment: I don’t understand. What’s wrong with the Enter key being on the right-side of the keyboard? Where is your right hand? If it’s on the mouse, then why are you pressing Ctrl+V to paste? Just right-click the Omnibar and select *Paste and search*. If it’s on the keyboard, then what is the problem with Enter? (Apologizes for the—statistically reasonable—assumption if you only have one hand.)

Comment: @Synetech well the problem with clicking the omnibar is that it's always slower since i have to *aim* my mouse at the omnibar. I can always do Ctrl-E-A-V much faster than I can do a single click on a targeted spot.

Comment: Again, where is your right hand? Why can’t you just press Enter with it?

Comment: @Synetech my right hand is on my mouse. if i need to take my hand off my mouse and hit the enter key, then that would take too long. I can do Ctrl-E-A-V in less than half a second

Comment: Do you have a numeric pad on your keyboard? You can hit the Enter key on that with your right thumb without taking your hand off of the mouse.

Comment: @Synetech no i'm using laptop

Comment: Is it an external mouse or a track-pad? If it’s a track pad, can’t you press the Enter key with your right pinky?

Comment: @Synetech no one uses trackpad while working!

Comment: So you’re using Chrome to do work, changing the active page frequently, and using an external mouse because a trackpad is too inconvenient/slow for working as is leaving both hands on the keyboard? Okay.

Comment: @Syntech its nothing to do with the hands, but rather mouse gives a magnitude more freedom over the cursor than whatever precision the trackpad could offer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do an [AHK](http://www.autohotkey.com/) remapping, which isn't really an elegant solution, but will get you your shortcut with the least amount of effort:

```
^+v::
  IfWinActive, Google Chrome 
  {
    SendInput, ^v
    SendInput, {Enter}
  }
```

Your new savior would be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Wouldn’t that affect every text field in web pages, the Options dialogs and so on as well? I highly doubt that you would want Enter to be automatically pressed when you paste something into a text field since it would submit the form or close the dialog prematurely.

Comment: @Synetech it's mapped to `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`V`. No interference with the regular paste function.

Comment: I really should get around to learning Autohotkey and AutoIt (I’ve got them installed, but keep ignoring them because I’ve got other tools like HotkeyMaster to do those things). `:-|`

Comment: @Synetech If you already know another language and you can find the Windows Script Host libraries for it, use that instead. AutoHotKey is a horrible mess of a language.

Comment: At least AHK is regularly updated; some languages and tools aren’t so for example, it can no longer be used to adjust the volume in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean searching in Google. Given the fact that you right-click the address bar, you already use your mouse and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy a text that you again selected with your mouse before.

This means you switch from mouse (selecting) to keyboard (copying) to mouse (right-clicking) to keyboard (pasting and enter).

Better option: Download [Context Menu Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga), which searches for selected text using the context menu (right-click).

Steps involved: Select text (mouse), right-click and search (mouse). No keyboard necessary.

Comment: Or you could do Ctrl+C, Alt+TAB to Chrome, F4, Ctrl+V, all with the left-side keyboard.  All that's missing is Enter.  Ctrl+Shift+V will help keep it all on the left.

Comment: i don't ever click the address bar

Comment: @Pacerier *> **When we right click the address bar**, there is an option for us to do "paste and search"* ?

Comment: @slhck i don't ever click the address bar. but i know that info.

Comment: @Pacerier Ah, okay, didn't really understand that at first, sorry!

Comment: @slhck np =D hee give me a google+ invite pacerier@gmail.com

Comment: @slhck Lol cool ! that was really unexpected

Answer (score 1):

[Remap](http://www.google.com/search?q=remap+keys) <kbd>Left-Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> / <kbd>`</kbd> / etc. to <kbd>Enter</kbd>, using [whatever method](http://www.google.com/search?q=remap+keys) you like. That way, you aren’t messing up a key/combo that you actually use; instead you just “create” a new <kbd>Enter</kbd> key that is closer to your left hand.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Chrome Extension that does this without you even having to click on the address bar! You just click Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + E to search for whatever text you had copied to your clipboard. Hope this helps! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pastequery/dglpgijbinajkdnmplaegaofkgjmfdbg

Comment: The AutoHotKey for me does not really answer the question because it excludes users who do not use Windows.  Thanks, from a Linux user!